# Trouble using fsolve to find x-values of scipy.ODR with given y-values

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to utilize `fsolve` to find x-values based on known y-values of my `scipy.ODR` plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.odr import ODR, Model, RealData
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def func(beta, x):
    y = beta[0]+beta[1]*x+beta[2]*x**3
    return y

sqx = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16])
sqy = sqx**2

host = np.linspace(0,100,100)
modata = RealData(sqx, sqy)
model = Model(func)

sqc = np.array([sqy])[0]
sqc.fill(0)
sqm = np.transpose([sqy, sqc, sqc])

odr = ODR(modata, model, [1,1,1])
odr.set_job(fit_type=0)
output = odr.run()
yn = func(output.beta, host)
xvals = np.array([[fsolve(func, [10,10,10], args=((output.beta - sqm[hi]))) for hi in range(len(sqm))]]).flatten()
hosty = func(host, output.beta)
[plt.axhline(sqy[hi]) for hi in range(len(sqy))]
[plt.axvline(xvals[hi]) for hi in range(len(xvals))]
plt.plot(host ,yn,'g-',label='odr')
plt.legend(loc="best");
plt.axis([0,20,0,300])
plt.show()
print(xvals)
news = func(xvals, output.beta)
print(news)
print (sqy)
```

I'm able to accomplish my goal with a `curve_fit` function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit, fsolve

def sq(x, a, b, c):
    return a*x**(2) + b*x + c

sqx = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16])
sqy = sqx**2

meme = 10
host = np.linspace(0,20,100)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(sq, sqx, sqy)
xvals = np.array([[fsolve(sq, 10, args=(popt[0], popt[1], (popt[2] - sqy[hi]))) for hi in range(len(sqy))]]).flatten()
hosty = sq(host, *popt)
[plt.axhline(sqy[hi]) for hi in range(len(sqy))]
[plt.axvline(xvals[hi]) for hi in range(len(xvals))]
plt.plot(sqx, sqy, 'bo')
plt.plot(host, hosty, 'r-')
plt.axis([0,6,0,20])
plt.show()
print(xvals)
news = sq(xvals, *popt)
print(news)
print (sqy)
```

I can plot the values neatly and confirm I'm solving for the right numbers here.

But I can't seem to do this the same way if I want to use an `ODR` function. I'm confused as to how the notation would work out when I'm solving for `x` in my `func`. It's giving me 3x as many values as necessary because I have to put in 3 starting estimates when I use `fsolve` due to`func`'s `beta` indices.

I also can't figure what the best way of writing the actual arguments is, as putting `output.beta` acts as a single variable, but I want to solve my y-value so I need a subtraction to happen somewhere.

I've tried switching around `func` to accept input in different ways, but I can't get the `ODR` fitting to work when I do this. Is there any way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Suggested reading: [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's focus on the relevant code: you have

```
def func(beta, x):
    y = beta[0]+beta[1]*x+beta[2]*x**3
    return y
```

and

```
fsolve(func, [10,10,10], args=((output.beta - sqm[hi])))
```

According to [fsolve syntax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html), it solves for the first variable of `func` (which could be a vector). This means you are solving for vector `beta`, with initial guess `[10,10,10]`.  But from the context it's clear you want to get x, with beta being known.

So you need a wrapper around `func` to put the arguments in order. A simple example would be

```
fsolve(lambda x: func([1, 2, 3], x), 10)
```

which returns `array([-0.40231994])`.  Here `fsolve` gets a function of one argument x, and solves for it. And here is how it can work in your case:

```
[fsolve(lambda x: func(output.beta - s, x), 10)[0] for s in sqm]
```

I've made two more changes:

- use `x for x in xlist` instead of `x[i] for i in range(len(xlist))`
- pick the solution immediately with `[0]` instead of applying `flatten` later.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my problem. I'll take your advice and learn more about these things :)